# Ionic App: Display Google Directions steps

Tags: android, css, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm very new to this Ionic Framework, and so far, I'm loving it. It's great, simple and fast!

I'm developing a a simple app that shows a full screen map as the main view. The map has a set of markers, and when you click each marker, it will give you directions from your current location.

Everything is working fine, but I'm not sure what's the best way to display the directions steps (the instruction texts). I've first tried to put it in the side menu. It works but it's very ugly and uncomfortable to use.
Then I tried using an ActionSheet, this time it looks cooler, but I don't like that it has a backdrop, and that each item is a button. I know this is not what ActionSheets are intended, I was just playing.

So, I need something like an ActionSheet but I need more control over the rendering.
What do you think? What's the best way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a somewhat subjective question. However, Action Sheet is intended to be used for buttons and a Side Menu is meant for navigation. Both have default behaviors that would probably make your users annoyed, because they are conceptually the wrong UI components for this type of information. In particular they will auto-close if you tap in the wrong places, not good if you are trying to read or scroll the list.

You should use an ionList inside of ionContent to show direction steps so you can scroll in case the steps are larger than the available screen. You could have the steps show in a modal or you could just make it another state view that you can navigate to.

Comment: Yes, I know I'm using the wrong UI components, and all the annoyance you talk about are the exact reason I'm asking this question. I want to show the steps but still keep the map visible. That's why I thought about something like ActionSheet, but "slideable". The modal isn't a bad idea, I didn't thought about it. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: If you want the map to show, you could use the ionScroll component and show it below the map. You would have to handle the CSS to resize the map and declare the ionScroll height to make it layout how you want, but then the list could be scrolled below the map.